# Python: How to ignore an exception while still handling others

Tags: python, django, exception

I was messing with some code and was faced with a particular problem:

```
def find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    try:
        sender_node = object.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except object.DoesNotExist:
        instance.slug = slug
    else:
        slug = '%s_' % slug
        find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    return
```

The issue I am having is that sometimes `objects.get(slug=slug)` throws a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception because that field is not unique within my database. I wonder how I can cleanly catch `MultipleObjectsReturned` while the "else" statement will still get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, don't use the `else` clause at all:

```
def find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    try:
        sender_node = object.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except object.DoesNotExist:
        instance.slug = slug
        return
    except object.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        pass

    slug = '%s_' % slug
    find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: the trick is to trap `MultipleObjectsReturned` inside a second `try` statement, when calling the `get` method. This way, no exception is raised and execution continues normally.

Works:

```
def find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    try:
        try:
            sender_node = object.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except object.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            pass
    except object.DoesNotExist:
        instance.slug = slug
    else:
        slug = '%s_' % slug
        find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    return
```

Does not work:

```
def find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    try:
        sender_node = object.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except object.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        pass
    except object.DoesNotExist:
        instance.slug = slug
    else:
        slug = '%s_' % slug
        find_available_slug(object, instance, slug)
    return
```

The reason the second "naive" method does not work is that if an exception is caught, the interpreter will not go through the `else:` clause. It would instead silently `return`.

Comment: @sebleblanc.. Did you just answered your own question?? Or I became blind??

Comment: @RohitJain -- There's nothing wrong with answering your own question.  It happens somewhat frequently.

Comment: @mgilson..Well, just asked.. Because duration beween his asking question and answering it was mere few seconds only.. Else, there is of course nothing wrong..

Comment: @RohitJain, from the "Ask Question" page, you can check a box and add your own answer to the question.